# Can't create React Native application using WebStorm

Tags: react-native, npm, webstorm, yarnpkg

I want to create React Native Application using WebStorm. but some errors occurs while doing it.

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js init untitled
yes
prompt: Directory untitled already exists. Continue?:  (no) yes
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/sinamnouri/ReactNative/untitled
Using yarn v1.16.0
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.16.0
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/Users/sinamnouri/.config/yarn/link'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/sinamnouri/ReactNative/untitled/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native --exact
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:652:15)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:217:7
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:316:32
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:142:25
    at assembler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:313:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:322:32
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt.js:597:5 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 16730,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
Command `yarn add react-native --exact` failed.
Done
```

it looks like it's about permission, how can I handle permission in WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle permissions in WebStorm (and this actually has nothing to do with the IDE). Such errors usually mean that the `.config` folder in your `HOME` is not owned by you, so you have no permissions to write to it. Check if your user (the one you run WebStorm with) has the right privileges in `~/.config`, and give it the needed permissions ( `sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config` )